# Submit button with enter an url

Tags: javascript, forms, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet, which captures the url of the current page, where the user is, puts this url into a text field of a form on a page and then submits the form by *virtually* pressing submit button.

With following code i get the url of the current page, go to the site with url `http://example.com/?url=http://www.url-of-the-current-page`, fill the url `http://www.url-of-the-current-page` into the form's text field, but the form itself remains unsubmitted:

```
javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://example.com/?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href))})();
```

But how can i submit the form button? The whole form looks like:

```
<form ng-submit="launchTest()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> 
<input type="text" name="url" ng-model="url"> 
<input type="submit" value="Launch test" class="launchBtn" ng-class="{disabled: !url}"> 
</form>
```

I've tried two variants - and failed: in both variants i stay on `http://example.com?url=http://www.url-of-the-current-page`:

```
javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://example.com/?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));document.forms[0].submit()})();

javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://example.com/?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));document.forms[this.form.id].submit()})();
```

Comment: The form is inside the pop up? unless the page is on the same domain the JavaScript located on. , not going to happen.

Comment: The form uses `method="GET"`, since that's the default. You don't need to submit the form, just open the same URL that the form would open. Which should be what your first bit of code does.

Comment: @Barmar using the first bit of code (starting the bookmarklet with it) i go to the site with url `http://example.com/?url=http://www.url-of-the-current-page`, the url `http://www.url-of-the-current-page` is filled into the form's text field, but the form itself remains not submitted.

Comment: I think you need to look at what `launchTest()` does on the target page, and change your bookmarklet to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I've contacted the owner of the website, where I wanted to run my bookmarklet - he said, my bookmarklet is correct, but for submitting the form the url should contain a special parameter, like `&run=1`. With this parameter every bookmarklet mentioned in this thread works (works means not only opens new tab and inputs the url, but submits the form too). The working bookmarklet I'll use is:

```
javascript:(function(){var win=window.open('http://example.com?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href )+'&run=1','_blank');win.focus();})()
```